# Declare Cursor dynamically

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor, procedure

I need to create Cursors dynamically in stored procedure based on what situation i'm in, the ideal is below:

```
IF (varOrgGroupCode = '') THEN
BEGIN
DECLARE groupCode CURSOR FOR
SELECT `groupcode` FROM `LICENSEKEYS`;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE groupCode CURSOR FOR
SELECT `groupcode` FROM `LICENSEKEYS` WHERE `groupcode` = varOrgGroupCode;  
END;
END IF;
```

The code above will cause an syntax error. I've googled & someone did it by using temp table. Can anyone tell me how please?

Comment: what syntax error does it give?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the thing you found on Google was to create a temp table, populate that temp table based on your predicate and then reference the temp table in your cursor declaration.

Something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure`(IN varOrgGroupCode varchar(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE bNoMoreRows BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE vGroupCode varchar(100);

DECLARE groupCode CURSOR FOR
SELECT `groupcode` FROM `LICENSEKEYS_TEMP`;

declare continue handler for not found set bNoMoreRows := true; 

BEGIN

  drop table if exists LICENSEKEYS_TEMP;

  create temporary table `LICENSEKEYS_TEMP` (groupCode varchar(100));

  IF (varOrgGroupCode = '') THEN
    insert into `LICENSEKEYS_TEMP` (groupCode) SELECT `groupcode` FROM `LICENSEKEYS`;
  ELSE
    insert into `LICENSEKEYS_TEMP` (groupCode) SELECT `groupcode` FROM `LICENSEKEYS` WHERE `groupcode` = varOrgGroupCode;  
  END IF;

  open groupCode;

  GROUPCODE_LOOP: loop

   fetch groupCode into vGroupCode;

   -- Do some stuff

   if bNoMoreRows then
      close groupCode;
      leave GROUPCODE_LOOP;
   end if;

  END LOOP GROUPCODE_LOOP;

 END;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```